# Determine if a JavaScript file is already included via a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, include, telligent

I'm building several user controls (ASCX) for my website and several of them are very similar in what they do. (As a side note, I must create unique UC's even if they're similar because I'm creating widgets for the new [Telligent](http://telligent.com/) Community themeing system). For example, two of them are different but use the same front-end code to create a 2 or 3 tab panel where you can click a tab and it changes the data below. I have a single JS file to handle these tabs and the animations. I'm currently dynamically adding my JS file reference to the `<head>` from the user controls' code via:

```
Literal jsFile = new Literal();
jsFile.Text = string.Format("<script src=\"{0}\"></script>", "/community/themes/test/js/tabbedCallout.js");
Page.Header.Controls.Add(jsFile);
```

If I have both of these controls on a page though, both will add this JS file reference. How can I do a check to see if it is already added from another control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` (as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)?
This way you could add a key to each script you need and identify the script by its key!

Comment: +1: FTD: "Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not create a duplicate of the script."  -- Just use the same key every time you register the given JS file.  It will only be added to the page once.